# Рекурсивное решение алгоритма

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, рекурсия, функциональное-программирование

Имеется алгоритм для умножения каждого числа на все числа массива. Например, если массив состоит из элементов [2, 3, 7, 8, 10], сначала каждый элемент умножается на 2, затем каждый элемент умножается на 3, затем на 7 и так далее.
Я построил рабочий алгоритм, но хотел бы посмотреть, как его можно было бы реализовать с помощью рекурсии.

Мой алгоритм:

```
def expo(seq):
    sup_list = list()
    res = 0
    for i in seq:
        new = seq[:]
        for t in new:
            res = t * i
            sup_list.append(res)
    return sup_list


new_list = [2,3,4,5]
print(expo(new_list))
```

Не могли бы Вы показать мне, как эта же функция могла выглядеть рекурсивно?

Comment: А сразу перемножить все элементы массива, а потом умножить каждый элемент на результат - не вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов может быть много; вот, к примеру, реализация классического [divide-and-conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm):

```
def expo(seq):
    return _expo(seq, seq)

def _expo(seq, chunk):
    if not chunk:
        return []
    if len(chunk) == 1:
        factor = chunk[0]
        return [el * factor for el in seq]
    mid = len(chunk) // 2
    left_chunk, right_chunk = chunk[:mid], chunk[mid:]
    return _expo(seq, left_chunk) + _expo(seq, right_chunk)
```

Тесты:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize('seq, ans', (
    ([], []),
    ([0], [0]),
    ([1], [1]),
    ([1] * 100, [1] * 10000),
    ([2] * 10, [4] * 100),
    ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]),
    ([2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 8, 10, 6, 9, 12, 15, 8, 12, 16, 20, 10, 15, 20, 25])
))
def test_expo(seq, ans):
    assert expo(seq) == ans
```

Comment: Ваш алгоритм для меня, как для новичка, выглядит довольно устрашающе) Особенно последняя строчка, где происходит рекурсивный вызов функции. Но все равно спасибо за помощь, попытаюсь разобраться)

Comment: Это нормально для рекурсии поначалу, хотя в принципе цикломатическая сложность обоих реализаций сопоставима. Первые пять строчек - это условие остановки (два `if`-блока: что делать, если `chunk` больше нельзя разбить на две половинки). Если условие остановки не выполнено, разбиваем `chunk` на две половинки (`left_chunk` и `right_chunk`) и вызываем самое себя, только уже с этими половинками.

Comment: Ответ, который возвращается - это посчитанные списки для половинок, т.е. их надо сконкатенировать в один список, чтобы получить ответ. Т.е. принцип divide and conquer в действии - сначала раздели данные на части, посчитай ответ для частей (divide), затем соедини ответы для частей в один большой ответ для всей задачи (conquer).

Comment: Ага, то есть стратегия "Разделяй и властвуй", верно?) Проверяющие условия понятны, если список пустой, то выводится [], а если длина равна 1, то этот элемент умножается сам на себя и возвращается. Далее список разбивается: к примеру список [1,2,3] разбился бы вот так:  left_chunk = [1], right_chunk = [2,3]. А вот что происходит дальше, мне понять не удалось( Я так  понял - chunk - это список и объект наблюдений. А зачем тогда нам аргумент seq?

Comment: Не, если длина равна 1, то берется число - единственный элемент из `chunk` - и на это число умножается каждый элемент в `seq` (а-ля скалярное умножение вектора). Этот новый список и возвращается в качестве части ответа. Для этого `seq` и нужен, чтобы можно было его помножить, приходится таскать его за собой. Можно, конечно, реализовать это элегантнее (например, с замыканиями), но не хотелось переусложнять.

Comment: Так, так, минуточку....У нас же получается 'seq' и  'chunk' равны, верно? Если да, тогда понятно. А что делает рекурсия, не понимаю. А хотя подождите......Она чтоли делится так до того момента, пока не придет  к длине 1? Я правильно понял? Прошу прощения за мое непонимание, просто рекурсия и начинающие программисты плохо ладят)

Comment: Получается, в моем алгоритме реализована та же концепция, что и в вашем алгоритме, верно? Все из одного списка, умнажается на то же самое из другого списка по очереди. Надеюсь я понял все правильно)

Comment: Абсолютно верно - мы стартуем с двумя `seq`, одну просто таскаем за собой, другую упорно делим напополам, пока не разобьем на списки по одному элементу, тогда перемножаем, получаем много списков с перемноженными элементами и сливаем их в один список-ответ.

Comment: Насчет похожести - можно и так сказать, в конце концов, все дороги ведут в Рим :-)

Comment: Вы не могли бы мне посоветовать, каким способом лучше всего "перейти на ты" с рекурсией?) Есть такая поговорка - ты не поймешь рекурсию, пока не поймешь рекурсию) Как лично Вы осваивали эту тему?

Comment: Мне в университете доступно объяснили (я математический заканчивал), на первом же курсе CS-блока. Так что тут помочь не могу, увы - могу, конечно, посоветовать посмотреть темы в Corman et al и Korte & Vijgen, но это уже профлитература.